# Jest 24.0 -> Running Angular test very slow

Tags: angular, testing, jestjs

Jest 24.0 -> Running Angular 150+ Test suites - taking around 4500 secs on Mac and Windows and same set taking under 300sec on Ubuntu

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in Jest. We are facing the same issue in our project for over a year now. You can follow the issue on github [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7631).